# Any API for TSYS(TOTAL SYSTEM SERVICES)

Tags: reflection

It's a credit card company and is using a system called "Tsys" from "TOTAL SYSTEM SERVICES, INC". In order to get the information from the "Tsys", it's using Reflecltion for IBM 9 to connect to the "Tsys" server to get information. And for the sake of efficientcy, it's using VBA macro to simulate user's input in reflection to get information. However it's still very slow and easy to be interrupted by other application. 
For any people who is familiar with "tsys", is there any API(Java or C#) that allow people to communicate with the Tsys server directly without using third party software like reflection for IBM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

TSYS offers their TransIT API for developer integration. See [here](http://tsys.com/sdk/developer/index.html) to sign up and get access.